# Automate SQL code documentation in Github

Tags: sql, github, cicd

I'm looking for options to automate documenting my Postgresql SQL code in Github.

Every time I make changes to tables, views, stored procedures I need to put that on my github which is time consuming.

Anyone knows if there's a way to automate that so by just modifying my code, it will be updated on GitHub.

Let's say I have a view where I need to add some other columns and some other calculations which after the recreation I will be able to query. Once the code has been approved I would like that same code to be updated to my github account.

I was told that a tool named dbt would help me to achieve but after reading about it, I'm not sure if it will work.

Another approach is to use data migrations using python and django,https://realpython.com/django-migrations-a-primer/ , but I'm unfamiliar with it.

Is this related to CI/CD?

Any suggestions or ideas will be much appreciated.

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: For clarification, do you want automatic *documentation* or do you want *migration code that can recreate your database*

Comment: automatic documentation is what I'm trying to implement

Comment: Is this possible to achive? Automate the documentation of my code